# What make and model are these two small propeller planes?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-identification

What are the makes and models of the two planes in the picture? The registration numbers are ZS-JNJ and ZS-LCY, the year was 1981 and the place was Botswana.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

They're a couple of Cessna 210s. I can't tell from just looking whether they're Turbo 210s or normally aspirated. You can tell they're not 172s or 182s because they lack wing struts. Cessna 177s also do not have wing struts, but their front windshields are considerably different.

Comment: I (partially) own a 177 and I will back you up saying that these are definitely not 177's.

Comment: Yes, definitely 210. And not the pressurized P210, as you can tell from the windows. At first glance almost looked like 205s, or 206s, but the cantilever wing, retract gear, and window configuration give it away

Answer (score 0):

These may be Cessna 210 because of their looks and the visible sections. It is a turbo propeller aircraft with one engine.

Comment: While I believe there was/is a turbine powered conversion available, the 210s pictured probably had 285 hp Continental IO-520 engines. At least that's what the 210s had that I spent several hundred hours in.

Comment: Thank you,  I finally found a registration listing that shows ZS-LCY as a Cessna 210. ZS-JNJ is shown as a Cessna 310, but that has to be a re-use of the number. Thanks again for the clues.

Comment: Yes, C210s, but not necessarily equipped with turbochargers.